# Algorithm to determine maximum difference between different sets of a graph

Tags: graphs, dynamic-programming

I saw this image only, and it got me thinking: is this the maximum area difference between a contiguous region and Los Angeles County, such that the population of that region is smaller?

Formally, given a graph with nodes $i$ from $0$ to $n$, where $i = (p_i, a_i)$, with $p_i$ represent its population and $a_i$ its area:

Find the $max(\sum{a_c} - a_k)$ where $a_k$ is the area of some single node $k$, and $\sum{a_c}$ is the sum of areas of a contiguous region $C$ where $c \in C$, such that $\sum{p_c} < p_k$, and $k \notin C$.

I think it's clear $k$ is not guaranteed to be the node with maximum population, because it might have a large area. How would one construct an algorithm to determine the max difference in area?

[image: Text]

Comment: This problem is at least as hard as the knapsack problem, hence NP-hard in the general case.  It might be solvable well enough for a map of the US.